# Can't verify RSA-PSS signatures across openssl/golang 1.18

Tags: go, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to generate an RSA PSS signature with openssl in a bash script and verify it in a go microservice.  Verification fails across openssl/go.

**Generate the keys and signature (signature.bin) in openssl/bash...**

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 4096
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout > key.pub

truncate -size=16 zeroes.bin

openssl dgst -sign key.pem -keyform PEM -sha512 -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:64 -out signature.bin -binary zeroes.bin
```

**Use openssl to verify signature (ok)...**

```
openssl dgst -verify key.pub -keyform PEM -sha512  -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:64 -signature signature.bin -binary zeroes.bin
Verified OK
```

**Go can create and verify its own RSA-PSS, but fails on the signature from openssl...**

```
go run main.go
Verified go signature.
panic: crypto/rsa: verification error

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /root/taas/applications.security.amber.core-services/pss/x/main.go:51 +0x339
exit status 2
```

**openssl also fails to verify the go signature...**

```
openssl dgst -verify key.pub -keyform PEM -sha512 -signature signature.**go**.bin -binary zeroes.bin
Verification Failure
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "crypto"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/sha512"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    privatePem, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("key.pem")
    privateBlock, _ := pem.Decode(privatePem)
    if privateBlock == nil {
        panic("Failed to decode private pem")
    }
    privateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(privateBlock.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    h := sha512.New()
    h.Write(make([]byte, 16))
    zeroes := h.Sum(nil)

    signature, err := rsa.SignPSS(rand.Reader, privateKey, crypto.SHA512, zeroes, &rsa.PSSOptions{
        SaltLength: rsa.PSSSaltLengthEqualsHash, // should be 64 for sha512
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ioutil.WriteFile("signature.go.bin", signature, 0600)

    err = rsa.VerifyPSS(&privateKey.PublicKey, crypto.SHA512, zeroes, signature, &rsa.PSSOptions{
        SaltLength: rsa.PSSSaltLengthEqualsHash,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Verified go signature.")

    opensslSignature, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("signature.bin")
    err = rsa.VerifyPSS(&privateKey.PublicKey, crypto.SHA512, zeroes, opensslSignature, &rsa.PSSOptions{
        SaltLength: rsa.PSSSaltLengthEqualsHash,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Not getting here -- crypto/rsa: verification error")
}
```

Comment: Which version of OpenSSL or LibreSSL? I'm unable to reproduce the issue after running your steps - I get the "Not getting here -- crypto/rsa: verification error" line printed. WRT "openssl also fails to verify the go signature" - I do get an error with the command you've specified, but adding `-sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss` resolves this.

Comment: OpenSSL version is 1.1.1.  But yes, I initially was not using the -sigopt parameters which has resolved my issues.